# How I do route passing 3 parameters into controller in C# mvc?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, router

The url format is:

```
http://0.0.0.0:5000/?id=author_name&id2=book_name&id3=123
```

I tried to make the roate for it, but it doesn't work:

```
   routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Main}/{action=Index}/{id?}&{id2?}&{id3?}");
```

And the method is:

```
   public IActionResult Index(string id, string id2, string id3)
   {
        return View();
   }
```

How do I set the proper route for passing 3 parameters?

Comment: I'm pretty sure in your case you don't need to put the querystring in the route template. It'll be done automatically by mvc.

Comment: @the_lotus so route template should be `template: "{controller=Main}/{action=Index}")` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure in your case you don't need to put the querystring in the route template. It'll be done automatically by mvc. Just use the "normal" route.

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

The variables in the get are automatically passed as parameters.

```
   public IActionResult Index(string id, string id2, string id3)
   {
        return View();
   }
```

Comment: Danke! It solves the question.